# How do i add a command line prompt as the $EDITOR when committing in svn and git

Tags: svn, git, editor, prompt, pre-commit

Is it possible to have a small shell script to replace the `$EDTIOR` for git and svn?

So when a person not familiar with vi or emacs makes a commit and forgets to add a
`-m "fixed the foo bug"`
parameters it would not open an editor they do not know how to exit, but instead it would just prompt

> Please proved a sentence on what this commit contains:

and the user just writes a small sentence, hits enter, and off it goes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply configure their `$VISUAL` to something they know how to use?

Answer (score 2):

For git you can edit your `config` file. Add `editor` to `core` section, and point to editor of your choice. For example notepad++ and git under cygwin:

```
[core]
    editor = git-core-editor.sh
```

Contents of `git-core-editor.sh`(put it in `cygwin/bin` directory) :

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession `cygpath -w -a "$*"`
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason we have `nano`, you know.

But you could use a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Show the message template so the user knows what's up
cat $1
echo "Type your message, or press return to abort:"
head -n1 > $1
```